# how to /clr compile "servprov.h" (IServiceProvider)

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to /clr compiling a project that need to "servprov.h" (IServiceProvider)

I faced to this ERROR:

> Error 2   error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol  116

it's part of code:

```
#ifndef __IServiceProvider_FWD_DEFINED__
#define __IServiceProvider_FWD_DEFINED__
typedef interface IServiceProvider IServiceProvider;
```

1- I changed all `IServiceProvider` to `::IServiceProvider`

at this part

```
typedef /* [unique] */  __RPC_unique_pointer ::IServiceProvider *LPSERVICEPROVIDER;
```

I faced to this error:

> Error 1   error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type
>   'System::IServiceProvider'    92

2- I changenged it to:

```
typedef /* [unique] */  __RPC_unique_pointer System::IServiceProvider ^ LPSERVICEPROVIDER;
```

and again I have error :( at this part of code:

```
typedef interface ::IServiceProvider IServiceProvider;
```

> Error 2   error C2371: 'IServiceProvider' : redefinition; different
>   basic types       99

3- I chenged it to:

typedef interface ::IServiceProvider IServiceProvider2;

and now I have this error:

> Error 3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0001CA) "public: __thiscall
>   cComponentManager::~cComponentManager(void)"
>   (??1cComponentManager@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void
>   * __thiscall cComponentManager::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)"
>   (??_GcComponentManager@@$$FQAEPAXI@Z) C:....\OpenSmileCLI\OpenSmileCLI\OpenSmileCLI.obj
>
> Error 67  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   void __thiscall ConfigValueObj::copyFrom(class ConfigValue const *)"
>   (?copyFrom@ConfigValueObj@@UAEXPBVConfigValue@@@Z)    C:...\OpenSmileCLI\OpenSmileCLI\OpenSmileCLI.obj

Is my changed correct?
what I should do?

"servprov.h" used by OpenSmileLibrary
 and I want to create CLI between C# and openSmileLibrary!

solution:

I change debug mode to release (cause of OpenSmileLibrary) and change position of using System after `#include "servprov.h"`.

for LNK error :

remove space in path directory.

Comment: Yuck, do not edit SDK header files, very bad idea.   The basic problem is that you have `using namespace System;` *before* the #include, that makes it ambiguous.  The link error is caused by forgetting to link a smiley .lib

Comment: @HansPassant: tnx, I linked all .lib files (related to OpenSmileLibrary) to my solution, but i still have 132 external error like as LNK2028 and LNK2001.